# VBA Error 1004: PasteSpecial method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I'm  having a bit of trouble with any kind of paste method I use at the moment. 
Data from one sheet must be cut and pasted to another, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

The error occurs here, shortly after the commented "HERE" :

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Full code can be found below, thanks for any replies.

```
    Option Explicit
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb As Variant
Dim wsName As Variant
Dim blastrow As Variant
Dim flastrow As Variant
Dim lastrow As Variant


    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("combined").Select

   Range("A1:U9999").ClearContents

   Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   file = Dir("G:\BS\Josh Whitfield\Credit_Chasing\NEW PROCESS\")
   'file level loop
   While (file <> "")
    If InStr(file, ".xlsx") > 0 Then
    Workbooks.Open "G:\BS\Josh Whitfield\Credit_Chasing\NEW PROCESS\" & file
    wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'ws = ActiveSheet.Name

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'worksheet/tab level loop
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Activate
            wsName = ws.Name

            'andrew code (09/12/2015)
            blastrow = Workbooks("Copy of merge.xlsb").Worksheets("Combined").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If blastrow = 2 Then blastrow = 1
            Workbooks("Copy of merge.xlsb").Worksheets("Combined").Range("A" & blastrow & ":XFD" & blastrow).Value = _
                Workbooks(wb).Worksheets(wsName).Range("A1:XFD1").Value


        lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        'finding status column
        Range("M1").Select
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "Status" Or ActiveCell.Column > 100
            If Range("A2") = "" Then
                GoTo there
            End If

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop

        'looping through
    Do Until ActiveCell.Row > lastrow
        If ActiveCell.Value = "Solved" Then 'HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    wb = Replace(wb, ".xlsx", "")

        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
        Workbooks("copy of merge.xlsb").Activate

    'find matching company
    Range("E1").Select
    While ActiveCell.Value <> "CoName"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Wend

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = wb
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Loop

    'first cell in row select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select

    'find matching ws
    If ws = "Be Wiser" Then
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "BW"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    ElseIf ws = "Insure Wiser" Then
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "IW"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    ElseIf ws = "Call Wiser" Then
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "CW"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    ElseIf ws = "Quote Wiser" Then
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "QW"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    ElseIf ws = "Be Wiser Business" Then
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "BWB"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    ElseIf ws = "Younger But Wiser" Then
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "YBW"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    End If

    'insert row and paste
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        'lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Range("A" & lastrow).Select
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
        ws.Activate
        lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A19" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:U" & lastrow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("M1").Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "Status" Or ActiveCell.Column > 100
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Loop
Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If

        Loop
there:
            'here
            flastrow = Workbooks("Copy of merge.xlsb").Worksheets("Combined").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            If blastrow = flastrow Then
                Workbooks("Copy of merge.xlsb").Worksheets("Combined").Activate
                Range("A" & blastrow).Select
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
                Workbooks(wb).Worksheets(wsName).Activate
            End If

           Next ws

        Workbooks(wb).Close False

      End If
     file = Dir
  Wend

  Call storeFileNames

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't **Cut** and Paste values. If you cut, you can only paste the whole range including formatting.

Comment: I've changed that to PasteAll and it still isn't working, I'll remember that though.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. you can't use `PasteSpecial`, you have to either use `Paste` (Worksheet method, not range) or the `Destination` argument of the Cut method.

Comment: Ah, I see. How would you recommend I pasted then? I've now removed that faulty line and replaced the line above it with `ActiveCell.EntireRow.paste`, but thats giving me another error _Object doesn't support this property or method_. The destination is also very variable, so I'm not certain how I would use the `Destination` argument, hence the offset loop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code is very difficult to maintain because it uses *extensively* a non-recommended method based on `Activate` and `Select`. A good advice is to rewrite it completely without ever using `Select`, but only by saving the concerned ranges inside variables of type `Range`. If you do that, it will be very easy to write things like `srcRange.cut destRange`, or even if you want to copy values it would be possible by doing `src.copy; dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues; src.ClearContent`.

Comment: I suppose I will have to try that then, quite a pain since in the original code (without some of the complications) works fine. Thank you very much for your help, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been noted, you really ought to rewrite this, but as a quick fix, add a range variable:

```
Dim rgCut as Excel.Range
```

then instead of this:

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
```

use:

```
set rgCut = ActiveCell.EntireRow
```

and then replace this:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

with this:

```
rgCut.Cut Destination:=Selection.Cells(1)
```